# VBA in Excel to control Content Control Checkbox in a Word Document

Tags: excel, vba

I have researched numerous posts on this topic and below is the code I have come up with in a Standard Module in Excel to try and accomplish marking a Content Control Check Box in a Word Document as True, but I seem to be missing a key piece of code and am unable to figure out what that piece of code is that is causing this code to not execute and leave the Control Check Boxes unchecked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub TitleOrder_Click()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim cc As ContentControl  'Maybe this should this be Dim cc as object instead??"

    ContLoanFile.Hide

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SaveAsName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Title Order Form - " & Split(wsSI.Range("PBName"))(2) & ".docx"

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="Z:\Title Work Template.docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    Set cc = WordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("mpfPlat").Item(1)

    If wsFI.Range("Plat_DrawingYes") = "TRUE" Then
        If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
            cc.Checked = True
        End If
    End If


    WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAsName
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to explain exactly what the problem is - what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Sorry - its been a  long day.  The Content Control Checkbox on the word doc remains unchecked no matter if the cell  that is referenced has a value of "TRUE" or "FALSE".  I did also look to see if the word document was opening in read only and it isnt.

Comment: Does your module have "Option Explicit" at the top?  If not I'd recommend adding it and recompiling your code. Does your code know what `wdContentControlCheckBox` represents?  If you don't have a reference to the Word object library then you'll need to define that constant.

Comment: Yes, it has the "Option Explicit" at the top(I learned early on that having that is best practice).  I do not have `wdContentControlCheckBox` as a constant.  I have never declared a constant, but i do understand the logic behind it.  I will research how to declare `CONST wdContentControlCheckBox`.  I do have the Word Object Library referenced in Tools > Reference as well.

Comment: If you have option explicit set and a reference to the Word library then you're all set.  Have you debugged to see if `If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then` actually passes?

Comment: It was actually the `If wsFI.Range("Plat_DrawingYes") = "True" Then` that was causing the issue.  Once i removed the quotation marks around the word True it worked as expected.  Thanks again for your help Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that was causing this not to work was because of how I set the cell value based on a Check Box UserForm Control.  I thought the value in the Cell was a Text String, but it apparently wasn't (not sure why), so once I removed the "" from around the workd "TRUE" in `If wsFI.Range("Plat_DrawingYes")="TRUE"` the code ran as expected.  Below is the solution.  Thanks @Tim Williams for the assistance.

```
Private Sub TitleOrder_Click()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim cc As ContentControl  'Maybe this should this be Dim cc as object instead??"

    ContLoanFile.Hide

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SaveAsName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Title Order Form - " & Split(wsSI.Range("PBName"))(2) & ".docx"

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="Z:\Title Work Template.docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    Set cc = WordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("mpfPlat").Item(1)

    If wsFI.Range("Plat_DrawingYes") = TRUE Then
        If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
            cc.Checked = True
        End If
    End If


    WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAsName
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```